# Marklogic: How can we perform the case-insensitve search in a pure SPARQL query?

Tags: sparql, marklogic

I have a scenario where i am trying to find the content using the SPARQL query for the triples stored in marklogic. The filter condition in SPARQL query needs to perform the case-insensitve search for a particular term. May i know how can i do that?

For eg:

```
filter(strstarts(?personName, "FA"^^xs:string))
```

The above filters should fetch me the results whose personName value starts with upperCase also(like: fa). I think this will clearly give some idea about the issue i am asking about.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have two options to do case-insensitive search using SPARQL in MarkLogic.

If you want to use SPARQL only than you can do the following (modify the select statement as needed):

```
select * where {
  ?personName ?p ?o
  FILTER (lcase(str(?personName)) = "fa"^^xs:string)
}
```

As an alternative you could also mix some fn:* functions with your SPARQL statement so you could do something similar to:

```
prefix fn: <http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions#>

select * where {
 ?personName ?p ?o
 FILTER (?personName, fn:lower-case("FA"))
}
```

Don't forget that in MarkLogic you can use any fn:* or cts:* function as well (the prefix for cts:* functions would be `prefix cts: <http://marklogic.com/cts#>`

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes you are right. But applying these functions is impacting the performance. Since we are transforming the every personName by applying the functions the query performance is degraded.

Answer (score -1):

Next to the good suggestions of Tamas, there is also [`REGEX`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-regex). It accepts a case-insensitivity flag. Something like:

```
select * where {
  ?personName ?p ?o
  FILTER( regex(str(?personName), "^fa", "i") )
}
```

HTH!

Comment: Yes you are right. Even i have tried with these options, but these will have performance impact in fetching the results. As i read in some blog that using regex will have a impact on the performance. Since we use regex expression on every personName we have significant increase in time to fetch the results.

Comment: Sure, the more complex your sparql query, the more performance can be impacted. But how much is something you best measure yourself, with actual data. Regex is often told to be slow, but how slow might depend on the brand of triple store. lcase could be faster, and within MarkLogic perhaps a cts:contains with a cts:word-query that ignores case might be fastest. Hard to tell, as it also might depend on the data (volume, diversity, etc), and what else you do in the sparql query.